# When calling socket.close() in a ProcessPoolExecutor the connection is not closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

## The idea

- I have a server socket listening and accepting connections in the main thread
- I want to to have multiple threads to handle the client socket connections (using the `connection_pool` with `max_workers=10`)
- the data from the client socket should be handled by an other thread pool (using the `writing_pool` with `max_workers=1`)

## The problem

to me it seams like the client socket connections are not closed when i pass the client to the `ProcessPoolExecutor` and call the `close` function in the passed function which is executed by the `connection_pool` executor

## The possible cause

I guess that the passed `client` is probably not passed by reference `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

## Code

```py
import socket
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

connection_pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
writing_pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)


def addData(data):
    try:
        print("ADD DATA: " + data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("[!] error", e)
        return 1
    return 0


def handleClient(client: socket):
    try:
        print("HANDLE CLIENT")
        data = client.recv(1024).decode()
        client.close()
        print("HANDLED CLIENT")
        writing_pool.submit(addData, data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("[!] error", e)
        return 1
    return 0
```

### Working example (when not closing the client in the `ProcessPoolExecutor` but in the main thread were the client was created)

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        listener.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4040))
        listener.listen()
        while (True):
            client, addr = listener.accept()
            print("HANDLE CLIENT")
            data = client.recv(1024).decode()
            client.close()
            print("HANDLED CLIENT")
            addData(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("[!] error", e)
        raise e
    finally:
        listener.close
```

### Not working example (when closing the client in the `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of the main thread were the client was created)

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        listener.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4040))
        listener.listen()
        while (True):
            client, addr = listener.accept()
            print("CONNECTION")
            connection_pool.submit(handleClient, client)
    except Exception as e:
        print("[!] error", e)
        raise e
    finally:
        listener.close
```

### How I am testing the implementation

I test it using `netcat` executed by bash

```bash
for data in {1..9}; do echo "$data" | nc 127.0.0.1 4040 -q 1 ; done
```

## Environment

| Software | Version |
| --- | --- |
| OS | Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS |
| Python | Python 3.10.6 |
| Netcat | OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.218-4ubuntu1) |
| Bash | GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) |

Comment: I don’t believe you can pass sockets as arguments to other processes. They reference process-specific data. You can pass a socket to another thread on the same process.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thanks for your comment <3 can you probably provide me an example or tutorial on how to achieve this. I am new to python. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `ProcessPoolExecutor` because it is designed for parallel processing using separate processes which cause problem here because it cant access the memory spaces when you call `client.close()` in the `handleClient` function.

`ThreadPoolExecutor` will allow you to share the socket object directly between threads because it creates a pool of threads within the same process, so when we close the socket in one thread it will effectively close it for all other threads as well

```
import socket
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

connection_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
writing_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

def addData(data):
    try:
        print("ADD DATA: " + data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("[!] error", e)
        return 1
    return 0

def handleClient(client: socket.socket):
    try:
        print("HANDLE CLIENT")
        data = client.recv(1024).decode()
        client.close()
        print("HANDLED CLIENT")
        writing_pool.submit(addData, data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("[!] error", e)
        return 1
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        listener.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4040))
        listener.listen()
        while (True):
            client, addr = listener.accept()
            print("CONNECTION")
            connection_pool.submit(handleClient, client)
    except Exception as e:
        print("[!] error", e)
        raise e
    finally:
        listener.close()
```